# How to use Facebook login with http in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, facebook

I want to use Facebook login button in laravel app  but they are not allowing with HTTP..i was wondering if there any way we can use Facebook button without HTTPS

Comment: Please add what you have tried already. Show your current implementation that is not working including the error message. You can call facebooks https without having https on your own. You simple don't use something like `http://api.facebook ...` but instead `https://api.facebook ...`

Comment: No, that is not possible any more. Get SSL.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible as long as Facebook does not allow unsecured connections, you have to use HTTPS. You can use free Let's Encrypt certificate to secure your web app.